How to make MH-ET live scanner automatically scan when I put a qr code in front of it?
we are making a project that uses this type of scanner to scan QR codes. The MH-ET live scanner only scans/operates when the button beside it pressed. How can we make it constantly on, so that a staff can scan the QR/Barcode, without pressing the button one at a time?
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

const char* ssid = "1234";
const char* password = "*********";

String apiEndpoint = "http://domain/api/read_qr_kds";

//const unsigned char Passive_buzzer = 2;

String raw_data = "";
bool new_data_available = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Make sure this matches the baud rate of your QR scanner

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

//  pinMode(Passive_buzzer, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  while(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
  // Read serial data and construct the raw_data string
    while (Serial.available()) {
      char input = Serial.read();
      
      // Check if the character is printable before adding it to raw_data
      if (isPrintable(input) || input == '\n') {
        raw_data += input;
      }
  
      // If we receive a newline character, set the flag
      if (input == '\n' && raw_data.length() > 1) {
        new_data_available = true;
      }
    }
  
    // If new data is available, process it
    if (new_data_available) {
      Serial.println(raw_data);
      
      // Encode the raw_data before sending
      String encodedData = urlencode(raw_data);
      sendQRDataToAPI(encodedData);
      
      raw_data = ""; // Reset raw_data after sending
      new_data_available = false; // Reset the flag
    }
  }
}

void sendQRDataToAPI(String data) {
    HTTPClient http;
    WiFiClient client;
    
    String link = apiEndpoint + "?raw_data=" + data;
    Serial.println(link);

    http.begin(client, link);
    int httpCode = http.GET();
  
    if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
      Serial.println(httpCode);
      String response = http.getString();
      Serial.println("API Response: " + response);

      // Parse the JSON response
      StaticJsonDocument<512> doc;
      DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, response);
      
      if (!error) {
        int orderId = doc["qrData"]["OrderID"];
        Serial.print("OrderID: ");
        Serial.println(orderId);
        const char* status = doc["status"];
        Serial.print("Status: ");
        Serial.println(status);
      } else {
        Serial.print("JSON deserialization failed: ");
        Serial.println(error.c_str());
      }
    } else {
      Serial.print("HTTP Error code: ");
      Serial.println(httpCode);
    }
  
    http.end();
}

// Encoding the raw_data before sending it to the API
String urlencode(String str) {
    String encodedString = "";
    char c;
    char code0;
    char code1;
    
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c == ' ') {
            encodedString += '+';
        } else if (isalnum(c)) {
            encodedString += c;
        } else {
            code1 = (c & 0xf) + '0';
            if ((c & 0xf) > 9) {
                code1 = (c & 0xf) - 10 + 'A';
            }
            c = (c >> 4) & 0xf;
            code0 = c + '0';
            if (c > 9) {
                code0 = c - 10 + 'A';
            }
            encodedString += '%';
            encodedString += code0;
            encodedString += code1;
        }
        yield();
    }
    return encodedString;
}

What can I do to my device and waht can I add to my code so it can scan automatically?

So what you can do is bring the scanner in auto detection mode which can be done by scanning QR code in manual of MH ET scanner, then it will detect qr code automatically and you will not need to press button.
